# Visual Studio project setup to build external dependencies from source

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

My setup consists of three separate projects:

- **MyApp** - C# application. References **CLibraryWrapper** (includes as a git submodule)
- **CLibraryWrapper** - C# class library which is a C# wrapper for native C library. Depends on **CLibrary** (includes it as a git submodule)
- **CLibrary** - C shared library.

```
C# platform=AnyCPU                     C# platform=AnyCPU
+----------------+     References      +------------------------+
|     MyApp      +--------------------->    CLibraryWrapper     |
|                |                     |                        |
| MyApp.sln      |                     | CLibraryWrapper.sln    |
| MyApp.csproj   |                     | CLibraryWrapper.csproj |
|                |                     |                        |
+----------------+                     +-------+----------------+
                                               |
                                               | Depends
                                               |
                                               v
                                       C Shared Library
                                       +------------------+
                                       |     CLibrary     |
                                       |                  |
                                       | CLibrary.sln     |
                                       | CLibrary.vcxproj |
                                       |                  |
                                       +------------------+
```

### Question #1

I should be able to build **CLibraryWrapper** for `AnyCPU` platform and that requires setting up **CLibraryWrapper** project
in a such way that it would build **CLibrary** for `x86` and `x64` platforms. I'm loading `CLibrary.dll` at run-time depending on the process platform so I need both (x86 and x64) binaries to be present.

End result after **CLibraryWrapper** `AnyCPU` build should look like this:

```
|_bin/Debug/
  |_CLibraryWrapper.dll
  |_x86/
    |_CLibrary.dll
  |_x64/
    |_CLibrary.dll
```

Is there a way to achieve this in Visual Studio build configuration?

### Question #2

**MyApp** should be able to add **CLibraryWrapper** as a project reference.

End result should be that **MyApp** builds **CLibraryWrapper** which in turn builds `x86/CLibrary.dll` and `x64/CLibrary.dll`.
This way **MyApp** would be built with all it's dependencies from source code.

I've read that you can't reference `solution` from another `solution`. And solution controls build dependencies. I would really like **MyApp** to reference **CLibraryWrapper** and inherit `CLibrary` build configuration.

I was not able to find out how to setup my **Visual Studio** build configuration this way.

Comment: Hi friend, please check [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280101/any-cpu-not-available-in-c-c-solution). Not sure if the first answer from Peter can help. (But I think you can have a try with it)

Comment: And for the question1, as i know there has no option or setting for this situation. What if we use pre-build event to copy the output of CLibrary to bin folder of ClibraryWrapper, and then load them at run-time with relative path like [this simple](https://github.com/kevin-marshall/Managed.AnyCPU) from Kevin.